# Editing rules for employee rostering example

Tags: optaplanner, rostering, optaweb-employee-rostering

I am currently implementing [this](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering) for my project.

I need to add a rule for "at most four shift assignments per week per employee." I am new to java and drools. Is there an easy way to edit the rule below to match the constraint I am looking for?

```
rule "At most one shift assignment per day per employee"
when
    $s : Shift(
            employee != null,
            $e : employee,
            $leftDay : startDateTime.toLocalDate())
    Shift(
            employee == $e,
            startDateTime.toLocalDate() == $leftDay,
            this != $s)
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [accumulate](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.11.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_conditional_element_code_accumulate_code)

Your rule could look like this (I haven't tested it, but it should point you in the right direction):

```
rule "At most four shift assignment per week per employee"
when
    $shiftWeek: ShiftWeek() //assuming this is some kind of problemfact you have in your session
    $employee: Employee()
    $count: Number(intValue() > 4) //conditional, only fire rule when $count > 4
        from accumulate(
            $shift: Shift(
                $employee == employee,
                $shiftWeek == shiftWeek
            ),
            count($shift)
        )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 4 - $count.intValue()); //You could also just do "- $count.intValue()", but I like the constraint match to start at -1
end
```

Comment: How is the ShiftWeek problem fact defined?  Also, is there a way to modify this rule so that its checking for 4 consecutive shift assignments (eg, 1 per day, 4 days in a row)?

Comment: @Jeff ShiftWeek could be a list of problem facts containing the different weeknumbers for the roster. I made it up for this answer. It is probably just an object containing a week number and a year or something, and all shifts in the same week have a link to it. This problem fact is necessary because the rule must only be evaluated per week, per employee. I see you have opened a separate question for your 4 consecutive shift assignments question, I'll look into it later today.

Comment: @n1ck I'm a beginner in optoplanner, andI have the same type of use case : a rule for 'n shifts in a row'. Reading your answer with the ShiftWeek problem fact, I'm trying to guess. Would the solution for 'n shift in a row' be in relation with the creation of problem fact instances for all possible n days rolling window ? (with a shift having several links to all the containing n days rolling window problem fact ?)

Comment: @Stephane It's probably better to open a separate question with more details for your problem, but the nurse rostering example (https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl) has rules with minimum and maximum consecutive working days, so maybe you could take some inspiration from that.

Comment: @n1ck Thanks ! I didn't know that the nurse rostering example in optoplanner had these rules (I was learning from the optaweb example https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/7eebf6c0612591f03daeedeb2aa97cc7d6c393d1/employee-rostering-server/src/main/resources/org/optaweb/employeerostering/server/solver/employeeRosteringScoreRules.drl that doesn't have them). I'm doing to do my homeworks and open a question if necessary.